# Grouping By in Java on a tuple like Objects

Tags: java, java-8

I have a unique SET of location objects with data like

```
location 1: "USA", "AZ", "Phoenix"
location 2: "USA", "AZ", "Scottsdale"
location 3: "USA", "AZ", "Peoria"

Front end needs following json structure to render UI:

"USA"-> [{"AZ" -> ["Phoenix", "Scottsdale","Peoria"]},
         {"MD" -> ["Baltimore", "Gaithersburg","OwingsMills"]}
        ]
```

Java POJO for Location.java

I have written code which is bunch of lines to iterate through Set of locations and construct Country Objects containing Set of State Objects containing Set of City Objects using FacetsGeo object and generate json out of this data models.

I am thinking, there could be better way to do this : probably with Java 8 Streaming API.

Any help appreciated, as I said above is sample data, how flat Locations constructed.

```
public class Location {

        private final String country;
        private final String state;
        private final String city;

        public Location(final String country, final String state, final 
                String city) {
           this.country = country;
           this.state = state;
           this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object thatLocation) {

            if (thatLocation == this) return true;
            if (!(thatLocationCriteria instanceof Location)) {
                return false;
            }
            Location location = (Location) thatLocation;

            return Objects.equals(this.country, location.country) && 
             Objects.equals(this.state, location.state) && 
             Objects.equals(this.city, location.city);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.country, this.state, this.city);
        }
    }
```

FacetsGeo.java

```
public class FacetsGeo {
    private String label;

    private String value;

    private String type;

    private String subtype;

    private List<FacetsGeo> childFacetsGeo;

 }
```

What I tried to generate above front end data structure:

```
`       List<FacetsGeo> facetsList = new ArrayList<FacetsGeo>();

    Optional<locations> locationsOptional = Optional.ofNullable(locations);
    if(locationsOptional.isPresent()) {
        //locations 
        for (final Location location : locationsOptional.get().getLocations()) {
            FacetsGeo facetCountry = new FacetsGeo();

            if(location.getCountry() != null 
                    && location.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("United States") 
                    && location.getState() != null) {
                boolean countryExists = false;
                for(FacetsGeo facetGeo: facetsList) {
                    if(facetGeo.getType() != null && facetGeo.getSubtype() != null 
                            && facetGeo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("location")
                            && facetGeo.getSubtype().equalsIgnoreCase("country")
                            && facetGeo.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(location.getCountry())) {
                        facetCountry = facetGeo;

                        if(facetCountry.getSubCriteria() == null) {
                            facetCountry.setSubCriteria(new ArrayList<FacetsGeo>());
                        }
                        countryExists = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if(!countryExists) {
                    facetCountry.setLabel(location.getCountry());
                    facetCountry.setValue(location.getCountry());
                    facetCountry.setType("location");
                    facetCountry.setSubtype("country");

                    FacetsGeo subcriteriaState = new FacetsGeo();
                    subcriteriaState.setLabel(location.getState());
                    subcriteriaState.setValue(location.getState());
                    subcriteriaState.setType("location");
                    subcriteriaState.setSubtype("state");

                    FacetsGeo subcriteria = new FacetsGeo();
                    subcriteria.setLabel(location.getCity());
                    subcriteria.setValue(location.getCity());
                    subcriteria.setType("location");
                    subcriteria.setSubtype("city");

                    subcriteriaState.setSubCriteria(new ArrayList<FacetsGeo>());
                    subcriteriaState.getSubCriteria().add(subcriteria);

                    facetCountry.setSubCriteria(new ArrayList<FacetsGeo>());
                    facetCountry.getSubCriteria().add(subcriteriaState);

                    searchBarFacetsList.add(searchBarFacetCountry);
                } else {
                    FacetsGeo subcriteriaCity = new FacetsGeo();
                    subcriteriaCity.setLabel(location.getCity());
                    subcriteriaCity.setValue(location.getCity());
                    subcriteriaCity.setType("location");
                    subcriteriaCity.setSubtype("city");

                    FacetsGeo facetStateToAdd = new FacetsGeo();
                    boolean stateExists = false;
                    for(FacetsGeo facetState: facetCountry.getSubCriteria()) {
                        if(facetState.getType() != null && facetState.getSubtype() != null 
                                && facetState.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("location")
                                && facetState.getSubtype().equalsIgnoreCase("state")
                                && facetState.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(location.getState())) {
                            facetStateToAdd = facetState;

                            if(facetStateToAdd.getSubCriteria() == null) {
                                facetStateToAdd.setSubCriteria(new ArrayList<FacetsGeo>());
                            }
                            stateExists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!stateExists) {
                        facetStateToAdd.setLabel(location.getState());
                        facetStateToAdd.setValue(location.getState());
                        facetStateToAdd.setType("location");
                        facetStateToAdd.setSubtype("state");

                        if(facetStateToAdd.getSubCriteria() == null) {
                            facetStateToAdd.setSubCriteria(new ArrayList<SearchBarFacets>());
                        }

                        facetStateToAdd.getSubCriteria().add(subcriteriaCity);
                        facetCountry.getSubCriteria().add(facetStateToAdd); 
                    } else {
                        facetStateToAdd.getSubCriteria().add(subcriteriaCity);
                        facetCountry.getSubCriteria().add(facetStateToAdd);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }`
```

Comment: How do you map between Location and FacetsGeo? What does it mean by the fields such as label, value et.al in FacetsGeo? What have you tried so far? Please go through this before posting the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why do you want array of states? Wouldn't `{ "USA": { "AZ": ["Phoenix", "Scottsdale","Peoria"], "MD": ["Baltimore", "Gaithersburg","OwingsMills"] } }` be a better JSON?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas , I will try out your solution.

Comment: label : "USA", value: "USA", type: "Location", subType: "Country", childFacetsGeo : List<FacetsGeo> states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Java 8 Streaming solution, it can be done like below.

This particular solution doesn't generate exactly the same JSON shown in the question, because I don't think an array of state objects, with 1 key per object naming the state, is a good JSON structure.

If the JSON must be like shown in the question, then this solution will give a good start to get there.

```
Set<Location> locationSet = Set.of(
        new Location("USA", "AZ", "Phoenix"),
        new Location("USA", "AZ", "Scottsdale"),
        new Location("USA", "AZ", "Peoria"),
        new Location("USA", "MD", "Baltimore"),
        new Location("USA", "MD", "Gaithersburg"),
        new Location("USA", "MD", "OwingsMills"),
        new Location("CA", "ON", "Toronto"));

Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> countryMap = locationSet.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Location::getCountry, TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Location::getState, TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Location::getCity, Collectors.toList()))));

System.out.println(JSONWriter.valueToString(countryMap));
```

*Output*

```
{"CA":{"ON":["Toronto"]},"USA":{"AZ":["Phoenix","Scottsdale","Peoria"],"MD":["OwingsMills","Baltimore","Gaithersburg"]}}
```

Comment: `Set.of` is Java9++.

Comment: @Andreas could you pleas explain what is happening under the hood of this new API and is there any way getting Location data into FacetsGeo ( curious to know, if it is possible or not)